# looping through form elements to validate they aren't empty

Tags: javascript, dom

The following function loops through form elements to validate they've been filled in. The `bestresult` element is optional and if there's no user input, value of 0 should be inserted into to the form element. When I submit the form, fields with empty elements are submitted to the server instead of alerting user to provide values. Any thoughts?

```
function validateForm()
        {
            //Validates that form elements are not empty
            for(var i=0; i < document.results.elements.length; i++)
            {
                if(document.results.elements[i].value == null ||
                 document.results.elements[i].value == "")
                {
                    if(document.results.elements[i] == document.results.besttime)
                    {
                        document.results.elements[i].value = 0;
                    }else
                    {
                        alert("Error " + document.results.elements[i].getAttribute("name") + " must be given a value");
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: *"the form elements aren't validated"* What exactly happens? What is the outcome you'd expect and what do you get? Do you get a runtime error? Please provide more information, then it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: what is document.results  ?????

Comment: The code runs within a html page. When I leave some of the form elements empty, the form is submitted to the server instead of providing the user with an alert.

Comment: To make solving problems like this easier for you in the future [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function itself is fine. I've discovered there's been a problem with a regular expression which is not included in the code snippet